# How to understand the Sensor Setting Property ID in the SIG Mesh model

Tags: c, model, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, bluetooth-mesh

[image: MshMDL_]

I want to make a human body sensor and ambient light sensor. Which Sensor Setting Property IDs need to be selected and what is the data format?

I can't find information about Sensor Setting Property ID